# How to create looping dependency member voucher

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have table member, voucher and resign. There is a relationship between members and vouchers, where members can have many vouchers, and vouchers can have many members.

And also link to table resign.

These are the tables:

```
create table member
(
    ID int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
    memberno varchar(30),
    nameoncard varchar(30)
)

create table voucher
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
    voucherno varchar(30),
    memberno varchar(30)
)

insert into member values
  ('ai001','ali')
, ('ai002','badu')
, ('ai003','cica')
, ('ai004','dudi')
, ('ai005','efi')
, ('ai006','galih')
, ('ai007','heru')
, ('ai008','ina')
, ('ai009','joko')
, ('ai010','lambert')

insert into voucher values
  ('vc001','ai001')
, ('vc001','ai002')
, ('vc002','ai003')
, ('vc002','ai004')
, ('vc002','ai005')
, ('vc003','ai001')
, ('vc003','ai002')
, ('vc004','ai003')
, ('vc004','ai001')
, ('vc005','ai005')

create table resign
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
    memberno varchar(30),
    tanggalresign datetime
)

insert into resign values 
('ai005','2019-01-20')
```

From Resign table, the `memberno` has related voucher like below

1. memberno ai005 has voucher vc002 and vc005
2. voucherno vc002 has memberno ai003,ai004,ai005
3. voucherno vc005 has memberno ai005
4. loop from step 1 replace ai005  with ai003, ai004
   to get list voucherno have had by ai003, ai004 then cek what member had by these voucher.

I get six level with six script to achived this.

is there any solution to create query to get all list member in all voucher related to member resign.
but what i need is how to do it automatic looping like using CTE etc.

Please check for six script with six level here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/91256/21

Comment: have you tried adding `and m.memberno not in (select memberno from resign)`, `tsugiDateTime` will be taken into consdiration?

Comment: first level is member resign that is ai005, 
second level we get member ai003,ai004, 
ai005 but we need get level third using ai003,ai004 loop like first level.

Comment: i had created six script query to get six level manually from level1 to level6, but this is not an answer,
how to create query that looping from level 1 to end level, automatically looping using single script.

Comment: A fiddle link is a great addition to a question, but the question should not rely on it - it should be self contained. I've edited the DDL and DML of your sample data into the question for you, please keep in mind to include them in your future questions.

Comment: As it is now, your question is not very clear. Please [edit] it to include your desired results and current attempt.